# Bluez cannot pair

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have installed BlueZ5 from https://launchpad.net/~vidplace7/+archive/ubuntu/bluez5 on Ubuntu 14.04.  Everything works fine, I can scan, connect to devices that don't need authentication, etc.

However, I just cannot figure out how to pair successfully!  Anything I try in bluetoothctl results in an immediate error "Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled".  There is no request to okay the device or enter a code.

What I've tried:

- in bluetoothctl, "agent NoInputNoOutput" or "agent KeyboardInput", or the same as the command-line option.  Then interactively "default-agent", "power on", "scan on", "pairable on", "trust ", "pair ", and/or "connect "; and random combinations of these as well.
- running simple-agent from the bluez git repo in the background.  This just prints "Agent registered" but nothing after that, no errors and no prompts.

I've done this as a regular user in the netdev and plugdev groups and as root.

P.S. I think I need bluez5 because I am using BTLE devices.  But if anyone has a hint for how to do the same in bluez4, that would be cool too.